# Objective-C/Cocos2D - Display different Sprites with Animation on the same positon on the Screen

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hello i have a big question and i don't find a way to solve my problem till now.

I work on simple game with objective-c and cocos2D.

I have 3 different objects (sprites with animation) and four fixed position on the screen.

Alternately with a interval i want to display the different objects on the positions.

I wanted to do it with a double for() to position the objects. And in the for for i want to create a multidimensional array with all the objects.

And then i want to create a Method where i have access to the time-interval and the frequency of the different objects.

Do you think i can solve my problem with this solution or do you know a better way…??

It would be great if anybody could help me.

Thanky you

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"myPlist.plist"];
myArray = [[CCArray alloc] init];


for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
            Figure *figure = [Figure spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"a0001.png"];
            figure.position = ccp(j * figure.contentSize.width + 50, i * figure.contentSize.height + 50);
            [myArray addObject: figure];
            [self addChild:figure z:1];
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear . This question seems to be confusing. Do you only want to randomly position three sprites on four different positions on screen ?

Comment: your question isn't very clear, and I can't figure out what's on your mind. could you post the code you've created? maybe giving us some more information on exactly what you would do

Comment: Above is the code i have. This works with one figure. But the problem is, i want 3 different figures and each of them has its own animation. And i want to controll how often one figure cames out (with the animation).

I hope you understand. It is not so easy to describe. 

Thanks.

Comment: post the code that animates the figures. A hunch: if you use CCAnimate make sure each figure runs its own copy of the action.

Comment: Yes i use CCAnimate. But the Problem is, that i can only create one figure in my code above. I need a way to create 3 different figures. I want to create a game like this http://www.raywenderlich.com/2560/how-to-create-a-mole-whacking-game-with-cocos2d-part-1 But with 3 different figures and behavior. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you structured your plist, but I imagine that you have renamed the images in this way:

```
a0001.png
a0002.png
a0003.png
```

why you don't try to make a more simple for loop instead of a "for inside a for" for place only 3 images at your view and manage your file like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {

    Figure *figure = [Figure spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a000%i.png", i]]
    figure.position = //add something that fit with your layout
    [myArray addObject: figure];
    [self addChild:figure z:1];

 }
```